# mysql insert into if not yet existing

Tags: mysql

i am trying to insert something in MySQL table but only if it does not exist yet

from other posts I found this solution:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `settings` WHERE `name`= 'disable_new_user')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `settings` (`id`, `name`, `state`) VALUES (NULL, 'disable_new_user', 'true')
END
```

however this gives me a error message:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `settings` WHERE `name`= 'disable_new_user') BEGIN' at line 1
```

Comment: Where's the other code?

Comment: You add a unique constraint on column that cannot be duplicate. You use `INSERT IGNORE INTO yourtable (col1, col2) VALUES (val1, val2)`.

Comment: what other code? i just put this in the sql field in phpmyadmin and get  the error message